# HTML thinks object is undefined, when Typescript says it's not

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am using Ionic2 to iterate through a collection of `messages` and display them in a list.

I have code to output "`loading...`" if there `message` item is `undefined`. And it does display "`loading...`" on the screen, implying that `message` is `undefined`. But I also log the output from `!exists(message)`, and it indicates that `message` is not `undefined`.  So it looks like the `html` is not in agreement with the `ts`.

How is this possible? Any ideas how I can fix this?

**html**

```html
    <div *ngFor="let message of messages" class="message-wrapper">
        <div *ngIf="message && !exists(message)">
            <div *ngIf="message.changeDate">
                <center><span class="message-datetime">{{message.createdAt | amDateFormat: 'DD MMM YYYY'}}</span></center>
            </div>
            <div [class]="'message message-' + message.ownership">
                <div class="message-content">local:{{message.content}}</div>
                <span class="time-tick">
    <span class="message-timestamp">{{message.createdAt | amDateFormat: 'h:mm a'}}</span>
                <div *ngIf="message.readByReceiver && senderId == message.senderId">
                    <span class="checkmark">
          <div class="checkmark_stem"></div>
          <div class="checkmark_kick"></div>
      </span>
                </div>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="!message">
            <p>loading messages...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**ts**

```ts
  public exists(message: Message): boolean {
    console.log('exists: message = '+message.content+',   exists = '+(this.localMessageIds.indexOf(message._id) > -1));
    if (message) {
      return this.localMessageIds.indexOf(message._id) > -1;
    }
    true;
  }
```

**output:**

> `exists: message = test1,   exists = false`

You can see that the `message` item is not `undefined` as it has a `content` of "`test1`".  But the screen displays:

> `loading messages...`

[image]

**UPDATE**

Very strange.  I am testing using:

```
        <div *ngIf="message == null">
            <p>loading...</p>
        </div>
```

The console output shoes that `message` is not `null`.

exists: message = test3,   exists = false

But I still get:

`loading...`

[image]

Comment: `!message` can return true with too many values, you should check each case you need ( for example, message = 0 will return true)

Comment: You're checking for `message && !exists(message)` which is basically `if message is defined and its _id is lower than 0`. Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: @rinukkusu  yes, that is what I want. I have a list of local and server messages. exists determins if they are already there (index > -1).

Comment: That's some weird logic right there ... other than that I'd go with @Supamiu's comment.

Comment: @Supamiu and @rinukkusu. Thanks. I am just testing it with a more explicit `message != null`

Comment: That didn't work, so will test !!message

Comment: @Richard `!!message` is... wtf. I mean, `!message` is true if message is undefined, null, empty, 0, false, and maybe more. Therefore, `!!message` will be true in those cases...

Answer (score 0):

Just change your template by checking `messages` length instead of `!message`:

```
<div *ngFor="let message of messages" class="message-wrapper">
        <div *ngIf="message && !exists(message)">
            <div *ngIf="message.changeDate">
                <center><span class="message-datetime">{{message.createdAt | amDateFormat: 'DD MMM YYYY'}}</span></center>
            </div>
            <div [class]="'message message-' + message.ownership">
                <div class="message-content">local:{{message.content}}</div>
                <span class="time-tick">
    <span class="message-timestamp">{{message.createdAt | amDateFormat: 'h:mm a'}}</span>
                <div *ngIf="message.readByReceiver && senderId == message.senderId">
                    <span class="checkmark">
          <div class="checkmark_stem"></div>
          <div class="checkmark_kick"></div>
      </span>
                </div>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
<div *ngIf="messages.length === 0">
    <p>loading messages...</p>
</div>
```

Your goal is to display a loading message if you have no messages, therefore you don't have to check each message, because if you don't have any message, your `*ngIf` will no even get evaluated since `messages.length === 0`